# How to resolve configure guessing build type failure?

Tags: cygwin, configure

When I configure (under cygwin environment), an error occurred, Message are following:

```
$ ./configure
.................
checking build system type... /bin/sh: ./config.guess: No such file or directory
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

How to resolve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: File a bug with the package developer.

Answer (score 85):

search for `/usr/share/automake*/config.guess`

check the latest version of automake

```
$ which automake
$ automake --version
```

find the appropriate automake folder in `/usr/share/automake.1.11.1/config.guess`

replace `config.guess` from your build tree with `/usr/share/automake.1.11.1/config.guess`

(The same may/is usually needed for `config.sub`.)

Comment: Thank you for this! When building wxWidgets, I had to search recursively for config.guess & config.sub and just replace them all.

Comment: for AUR based build use following command to add to the PKGBUILD (prepare section):   cp /usr/share/automake-`pacman -Q --info automake|grep -i version| awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| awk '{$1=$1};1'| awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}'`/config.guess .

Comment: Does anyone know how to apply this for host name?

Answer (score 55):

## configure error: cannot guess build type you must specify one

This was solved for me by specifying the `--build=` parameter during the `./configure` step.

**For `arm64`**

```
./configure --build=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

**For `x86`**

```
./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: This fixed it for me in a different situation than OP. Thank you!

Comment: It addressed the issue on my arm board. Thank you~~

Comment: This has helped me at least 5 times now!

Answer (score 11):

The error message may also include instructions on how to deal with this.  In my case I saw

```
This script, last modified 2008-01-23, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
and
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD
```

In a browser I was able to access those files, save them to to my system, and then overwrite the respective ./config/config.guess and ./config/config.sub files in the package being built.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks I got it working.

- Just go to *C:\cygwin64\usr\share\automake-1.11*
- Copy *config.guess*
- Paste it to  *C:\cygwin64\usr\local\src\gateway-1.4.4*

Answer (score 2):

`config.guess` and `config.sub` routines are updated and kept on `github`;
You'll get the web pointers when you run the script,

```
./config.guess
```

In my `Mingw` system, `config.sub` or `.guess` were not in the `share/../automake-1.11/` tree, I needed to download the updated scripts which worked (when they replaced the old ones).

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me once the `config.guess` and `config.sub` files are updated. In my case, the config.guess and config.sub files are located in the same dir where I need to run `./configure`.

In summary, the following command worked for me:

```
wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD' -O './config.guess'
wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD' -O './config.sub'

./configure
```

Answer (score 1):

for AUR based builds add the following command to the PKGBUILD (end of prepare section) to have proper config.guess automatically applied/overrided in the package:

```
cp /usr/share/automake-`pacman -Q --info automake|grep -i version| awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| awk '{$1=$1};1'| awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}'`/config.guess .
```