# Getting Configure Error while compiling Corkscrew using Cygwin

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, configure

I am trying to compile corkscrew on a Windows machine using Cygwin. Now every time I try configuring it, I get an error which states that `configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one`

Here is the complete error log for those who would like to see it :-

```
Blueelvis_RoXXX@PranavVJituri ~/corkscrew-2.0
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... found
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for function prototypes... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking build system type... configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

I also tried using the `TARGET`, `BUILD` & `HOST` parameters but it was of no use as I am getting the same error.

Help would be appreciated on this matter :)

Comment: Have you had a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810996/how-to-resolve-configure-guessing-build-type-failure) Also [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91722/configure-error-cannot-guess-build-type-you-must-specify-one) links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the latest version of `automake`

`$ which automake
$ automake --version`

search for `/usr/share/automake*/config.guess`

find the appropriate automake folder in `/usr/share/automake.1.11.1/config.guess`

replace config.guess from your build tree with `/usr/share/automake.1.11.1/config.guess`