# configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one

Tags: cygwin, configure

I have a questition about an error occuring while I tried to install the GMP-Package with cygwin.

I already read through the other threads, however - the solutions suggested do not help me solving the problem.

I already installed the automake-package and I tried to procceed as suggested in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810996/how-to-resolve-configure-guessing-build-type-failure), however I am troubling where to insert config.guess since I do not understand what is meant by

> your build tree

Can somebody help me to solve my issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 (strongly suggested)
Install gmp cygwin packages:

```
gmp                                     6.1.0-3p1
libgmp-devel                            6.1.0-3p1
libgmp10                                6.1.0-3p1
libgmpxx4                               6.1.0-3p1
```

Solution 2 (to build your self)

It requires packages: Autoconf, automake, libtool

```
wget https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.0.tar.lz
tar -xf gmp-6.1.0.tar.lz
cd  gmp-6.1.0
autoreconf -ifv 
./configure
make
```

Comment: I get the message: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required.

Comment: which GMP software ? `https://gmplib.org/` gmp 6.1.0-3p1 is available on cygwin as package and its original source has configure.ac in `https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.0.tar.lz`

Comment: I already downloaded the gmp-package from its website. However, by installing gmp using ./configure --prefix=${gmp_install} it says the error mentioned above.

Comment: I suggest you to install the gmp cygwin package binary. In addition `autoreconf -ifv` in the source tree works fine

Comment: Where is the "source tree"? I tried autoreconf -ifv in the cygwin64-folder. However, the whole folder neither contents configure.ac nor configure.in.

Comment: You are clearly missing the basegroung : `tar -xf gmp-6.1.0.tar.lz` `cd gmp-6.1.0`  `autoreconf -ifv`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I now performed autoreconf -ifv correctly. However, now several errors occur saying "error: possibly undefined macro". The last line says "/usr/bin/autoconf-2.69 failed with exit status: 1".